# How can I align the text in the center of the image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a text inside a div, this div contains an image + another div which contains the text that needs to be centered.

See image the following image:
[image]

The problem I'm facing is that the image which is also in the div doesn't allow me to outline the text in the center.

I tried to apply padding and margins(even negatives ones) however with no results

So right now this is the code I have in my HTML & CSS files:

```css
.destinations {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.destinations img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 290px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-item-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="destinations">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="assets/img/wassenaar.jpg">
    <div class="flex-item-title">Wassenaar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach to vertically and horizontally center the text over the image:

```css
.destinations {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.destination {
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/500/500");
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="destinations">
  <div class="destination">
    <div class="title">Wassenaar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, this is the result I wanted. Is there also a way to have 6 different images since it uses the same background on all the other destinations?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your porblem solve using following css .

```
.flex-item{
     width:300px;
     height:200px;
     position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .flex-item-title{
 position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0;
        bottom: 0; left: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px; 
        text-align: center;
            color: white;
            display: inline-table;
           vertical-align:middle;
           line-height:100%;            
        }
```

Try changing your css to this css , it will work .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the problem i'm facing with this solution is that the text remains on the bottom of the div after the image

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer so that in future people can get the correct answer . Thank you . @Brickinwall

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer if you appreciate my work and if my answer got useful for you ? @Brickinwall Thank you .